# changing transparent_hugepage in docker

Tags: docker

I have a container which requires /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled set to "never". The host has this set to a different value, which I cannot change due to other applications running on the host. Is it impossible run a container with different transparent_hugepage values from the host? Both the host and the container are using CentOS 6.6.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you're referring to Redis, but unfortunately it is impossible.  Even if you give the container access to change kernel parameters (via `--privileged` or `--cap-add`), it would change for that container, the host, and all other containers.

The kernel is shared between the host and all containers so they all need to agree on the same kernel parameters. The only exceptions to this rule are those parameters within Kernel Resource Control Groups, or cgroups:

- PID: Process IDs
- UTS: Hostnames
- Network: Networking params like TCP backlog, etc
- Mount: Mounted filesystems
- User: UID/GIDs
- IPC: Inter-Process Control chit-chat is isolated

(more on cgroups: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)

Your specific request is related to a kernel memory-management parameter that applies globally.